# How To escalate workflow through code in AX 2012 X++

Tags: workflow, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I have Requirement of escalating a case management workflow to particular user if it has not been approved by the user to which the workflow has been assigned within the given time period. Now I was wondering how to escalate the workflow through code to particular user ? If someone can help me out

Comment: Why can't you use the existing escalation feature of the workflow?

Comment: no , because my requirement is little different , I am running a batch job and on some criteria I want to escalate all workflows that are in progress to particular user.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue using following method :

```
WorkflowWorkItemActionManager::dispatchWorkItemAction(WorkflowWorkItemTable, 
'comment',
 curUserId(), 
WorkflowWorkItemActionType::Delegate, 
'CaseDocumentDelegate' , false);
```